# Let $\rho$ be irreducible representation of finite group $G$ over complex numbers. Prove for central $g \in G$, $\rho(g)$ is multiplication by scalar.

Tags: representation-theory

Let $\rho: G \rightarrow \mathrm{GL}(V)$ be a finite dimensional irreducible representation of a finite group $G$ over the field of complex numbers. Prove that for every central element $g \in G$, the operator $\rho(g)$ is multiplication by a scalar.

Wikipedia says this is a direct consequence of schur's lemma (first paragraph https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_lemma) but I'm not sure why this is the case:

Comment: Because if $g$ is central then $\rho(g)$ is a $G$-linear map.

Comment: No need for Schur: Whenever $g\in G$ is central, each other $\rho(g’)$ (with $g’$ not necessarily central) must respect the partition of $V$ into $\rho(g)$-eigenspaces. Thus all of $V$ must be a $\rho(g)$-eigenspace for central $g\in G$, as claimed.

Comment: Schur's lemma applied to an irreducible representation $V$ over $\mathbb{C}$ says that if $T: V \to V$ is a $G$-linear map, then $T = \lambda \operatorname{id}_V$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. If $g$ is central, then $\rho(g)$ is $G$-equivariant.